# VScode debugger with docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-debugger

Recently i have started using docker for my project running with the following

- Django
- Nginx
- Gunicorn
- Celery
- Postgres
- Redis

Earlier it was easy to setup debugger but after using docker-compose i am not able to do that. As soon as i start the debugger it loads for sometime and then automatically stops with no logs or error anywhere.
Here are the relevant code.

launch.json

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "connect": {
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 443
        },
        "pathMappings": [
            {
                "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "remoteRoot": "."
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
 db:
     image: postgres:12
     env_file: .env
     environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
        - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
        - "5431:5432"
    volumes:
        - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
nginx:
    image: nginx:1.14
    ports:
        - "443:443"
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ./config/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        - ./myapp/static:/var/www/myapp.me/static/
web:
    restart: always
    build: ./myapp
    command:  bash -c "
                python manage.py collectstatic --noinput 
                && python manage.py makemigrations
                && python manage.py migrate
                && gunicorn --certfile=/etc/certs/localhost.crt --keyfile=/etc/certs/localhost.key myapp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:443 --reload"
    expose:
        - "443"
    depends_on:
        - db
        - nginx
    env_file:
        - .env
    volumes:
        - ./myapp:/opt/myapp
        - ./config/nginx/certs/:/etc/certs
        - ./myapp/static:/var/www/myapp.me/static/

broker:
    image: redis:alpine
    expose: 
        - "6379"

celery:
    build: ./myapp
    command: celery -A myapp worker -l info
    env_file:
        - .env
    volumes:
        - ./myapp:/opt/myapp
    depends_on:
        - broker
        - db

celery-beat:
    build: ./myapp
    command: celery -A myapp beat -l info
    env_file:
        - .env
    volumes:
        - ./myapp:/opt/myapp
    depends_on:
        - broker
        - db

volumes:
    dbdata:
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally i managed to solve it myself.
Few takeaways from the problem.

You need to use debugpy and place that in your **manage.py** file to start listening to a port.
I did something like this

```
import debugpy

debugpy.listen(('0.0.0.0', 5678))
debugpy.wait_for_client()
debugpy.breakpoint()
```

Along with this we need to map this port to a port inside the host machine. For that we need to change and add a single line in **web** service of docker-compose

```
ports:
    - "5678:5678"
```

And my launch.json looks like this

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "connect": {
            "host": "0.0.0.0",
            "port": 5678
        },
        "pathMappings": [
            {
                "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/myapp",
                "remoteRoot": "."
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

NOTE: make sure you have debugpy in your requirements file or install it manually.

Comment: Thank you for this great help, you gave me here! I was trying for hours to get some working configuration and yours just works like a charm!

Comment: You just saved my s

Comment: @targhs were you able to debug celery tasks as well?

Comment: @ReemaParakh i don't think i checked debugging celery tasks. Did you face any issue?

Comment: @targhs debugger is not working in case of celery task.

Comment: Seems like you have to attach the debugger to the process somehow. This only attaches it to the application running on the specific port. Can't help you more without going through the code

Comment: is that `manage.py` file is specific for Django project?

Comment: @ricoms its been a long time but yes i suppose so.

Comment: Thanks @targhs. I learnt that I need to include that debugpy import and call anywhere in my application code. I’m using fastapi and I didn’t have a manage.py file  I was confused about that

Comment: @ricoms in that case you can import it in your main application file.

Answer (score 3):

If you make your debugger a module you can turn it on and off with an environment variable.  I just used this article as the basis for a fastapi/gunicorn debugging solution.

```
# debugger.py
from os import getenv

def initialize_flask_server_debugger_if_needed():
    if getenv("DEBUGGER") == "True":
        import multiprocessing

        if multiprocessing.current_process().pid > 1:
            import debugpy

            debugpy.listen(("0.0.0.0", 10001))
            print("⏳ VS Code debugger can now be attached, press F5 in VS Code ⏳", flush=True)
            debugpy.wait_for_client()
            print("� VS Code debugger attached, enjoy debugging �", flush=True)
```

See this article by Adrian:  [Flask Debugging in VS Code](https://blog.theodo.com/2020/05/debug-flask-vscode/)

Comment: Thanks. It seems helpful. Will try to get this in my project.

Comment: @MrYutz, I'm using your solution now as well, which is kind of nice. There are just two things:
1) Why are you checking for `pid > 1`? 
2) If I call this function in the main() of my manage.py, it will run multiple times, resetting the debug server and waiting for a new connection.

Comment: @LarsSchellhas - "In debug mode Flask uses a first process (with pid==1) to start child processes that handle connections. If the code below this line is executed by the main process, the debugging port is taken and subsequent child processes can't use the same port and are attributed a random port which prevents connections."

Comment: Ah fair enough. I'm not using flask but Django, so I guess, adapting it in my way is ok :)